# GGPlot reorder variables between facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame (long format) which contains data from a personality self-report. I used ggplot2 to plot an exploratory factor analysis that I previously run. Below, I created a subset of my original data frame.

[Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-factor-analysis-results/), Dr. Dan Mirman suggested a nice way to plot this kind of data and I would like to do it. So, I have adapted his code but, as you can see from the image, the plot has an issue. Scales on y axis are alphabetically-reverse ordered. However, I would like to order those scales based on their loadings on each factor. For instance, I think the best order could be first "A", and "IdP" because they loaded strongly on Factor1, then "R", and "Ca" because they loaded on Factor 2, "InP" because it loaded on Factor 3, and "Co" because it loaded on Factor 4. At the bottom, "S" because it showed similar loadings on multiple scales.

Can anyone help me out? I would really appreciate it!

```
library(ggplot2)
Scale <- c("A", "IdP", "R", "Ca", "S", "InP", "Co", "A", "IdP", "R", "Ca", "S", "InP", "Co", "A", "IdP", "R", "Ca", "S", "InP", "Co", "A", "IdP", "R", "Ca", "S", "InP", "Co")
Factor <- c("Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor2", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor3", "Factor4", "Factor4", "Factor4", "Factor4", "Factor4", "Factor4", "Factor4")
loading.db <- c(0.93, 0.71, -0.15,  0.00, 0.34, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0.13, 0.79, 0.74, 0.43, 0.03, 0.06, -0.02, 0.30, -0.06, 0.25, 0.08, 0.66, -0.03, 0.09, -0.03, 0.18, -0.01, 0.37, -0.06, 0.62)

db <- data.frame(Scale, Factor, loading.db)

ggplot(db, aes(Scale, abs(loading.db), fill = loading.db)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Factor, nrow = 1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Loading", 
                       high = "green", mid = "white", low = "yellow", 
                       midpoint = 0, guide = F) +
  xlab("Test scales") + 
  ylab("Loading Strength") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

[image: Plot Factor loadings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to reorder your factor levels (see them with `levels(db$Scale)`. For example, here I sort them by looking at which ones are greater than 0.5 (in the order of factors 1, ..., 4), then add the ones that are missing at the end (`S` in this case).

```
lvls <- as.character(unique(db$Scale[db$loading.db > 0.5]))
lvls <- c(lvls, unique(levels(db$Scale)[!(levels(db$Scale) %in% lvls)]))

db$Scale <- factor(db$Scale, rev(lvls))

ggplot(db, aes(Scale, abs(loading.db), fill = loading.db)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Factor, nrow = 1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Loading", 
                       high = "green", mid = "white", low = "yellow", 
                       midpoint = 0, guide = F) +
  xlab("Test scales") + 
  ylab("Loading Strength") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

Gives

[image]